# Load certificate into xmlsec

Tags: c++, xml, sign, cryptoapi, xmlsec1

I need to sign xml using xmlSecDSigCtxSign. I need to create xmlSecDSigCtxPtr using xmlSecDSigCtxCreate method. I have PCCERT_CONTEXT found by CertFindCertificateInStore(). I'm calling xmlSecCryptoAppKeysMngrCertLoadMemory with success, signKey in xmlSecDSigCtx is NULL.
I'm feeling that I'm doing something wrong.

```
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
hStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, storeName.c_str());//storeName.c_str());
PCCERT_CONTEXT pContext = NULL;
pContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore,
                                      X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_HASH,
                                      &hashBlob, NULL);
xmlSecCryptoAppKeysMngrCertLoadMemory(mngr, pContext->pbCertEncoded, pContext->cbCertEncoded, xmlSecKeyDataFormatDer, xmlSecKeyDataTypeTrusted);
xmlSecDSigCtxPtr dsigCtx = xmlSecDSigCtxCreate(mngr);
xmlSecDSigCtxSign(dsigCtx, signNode);
```

May be I can init xmlsec specifying store?
Please, help.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @M func=xmlSecKeysMngrGetKey:file=keys.c:line=1253:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecKeysMngrFindKey:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=793:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=45:key is not found:details=NULL
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessSignatureNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=508:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxSign:file=xmldsig.c:line=291:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessSignatureNode:error=1:xmlsec library function failed:

Comment: The problem (i think) that dsigCtx->signKey is NULL.